# Included role doesn't run?

Tags: ansible

```bash
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.8
```

I'm trying to add a generic role that will delete files whose names are in a list. Here's my generic role, called `file-cleaner`.

*defaults/main.yml*

```yaml
remote_dir: "C:\\temp"
files_to_delete: []
```

*tasks/main.yml*

```yaml
- name: "Delete {{ files_to_delete }}"
  win_shell: del {{ item }}
  args:
    executable: cmd
    chdir: "{{ remote_dir }}"
  loop: "{{ files_to_delete }}"
```

I use the above role in another role, like this

```yaml
- name: Get name of old files
  win_shell: dir /b *.zip
  args:
    executable: cmd
    chdir: "{{ remote_dir }}"
  register: old_files

- debug: msg="{{ old_files.stdout_lines }}"

- name: Delete old files
  include_role:
    name: file-cleaner
  vars:
    files_to_delete: "{{ old_files.stdout_lines }}"
```

When I run my playbook, I see

```
TASK [role1 : Get name of old files] ***************************************
changed: [10.x.x.x]

TASK [role1 : debug] *******************************************************
ok: [10.x.x.x] => {
    "msg": [
        "file1.zip",
        "file2.zip"
    ]
}

TASK [Delete old files] ****************************************************
```

Like the included role didn't run, or wasn't even included. What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior (running ansible 2.10.7, because according to `pip install` there is no such thing as 2.10.8, and on Linux). The `Delete old files` task runs for each file in the `files_to_delete` list.

Comment: @larsks, thanks. Yeah that is strange. I have a Mac OS and installed Ansible via `brew install ansible` I believe

Comment: A dumb question, but if you put `debug` task in the `file-cleaner` role, do you see the expected value of `files_to_delete`?

Comment: No I don't see the `debug` task either

Comment: A task printing its name and that’s it, is usually what I saw on an empty loop. Maybe triple check that you are debugging the same think you are looping on?